# CSV to Json library not working in node js

Tags: node.js, csvtojson

I am trying to parse a csv file from the FTP server. The problem arises when the file has only one line of data. It works fine if the file has more than 1 line of data. The following code does the job. After debugging I figured out that fromString method does not return anything, However, the data from the socket is read successfully. Any help is appreciated

```
async function getFileData(ftpConnection, filename) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ftpConnection.get(filename, (err, socket) => {
      const products = [];
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
        reject(null);
      }
      socket.on('data', data => {
        csv({
          headers: HEADERS,
          delimiter: [';'],
        })
        .fromString(data.toString('latin1'))
        .subscribe((product) => {
          // Product is empty when its only one line
          products.push(product);
        })
      });

      socket.on('close', closingError => {
        if (closingError) {
          console.error('[Error]: ', filename);
          reject(null)
        } else {
          console.log("PRODUCTs")
          console.log(products)
          resolve(products);
        }
      });
      socket.resume();
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: maybe you can try to append an empty line or just a new line char ```\n```. Something like ```.fromString(data.toString('latin1') + '\n')```

Comment: atleast appending a new line character does not work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default csv2json assumes you have a header describing your csv file. If you have just one line this line is considered to be the header and therefore you have no data.

You can avoid this behavior by setting the `noheader` option to `true`.

```
csv ( {noheader:true} ).fromString ('1,2,3').then ((csv) => { console.log (csv); });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const CSV2JSON = async(dumb, editDumb, headers) => {
    try {
        log(`\n\nStarting CSV2JSON - Current directory: ${__dirname} - Please wait..`)

        if (!dumb && !editDumb && !headers) {
            var {dumb, editDumb, headers} = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2))
        }

        const options = {
            trim: true,
            delimiter: '|',
            quote: '\'',
            escape: '\'',
            fork: true,
            // output: "csv",
            // eslint-disable-next-line max-len
            headers: Array.isArray(headers) ? headers : JSON.parse(headers)
            // headers: headers,
            // noheader: true
        }

        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let counter = 0
            lineReader.eachLine(dumb, async(line, last) => {
                log(line)
                counter++

                let json = await csv(options).fromString(headers + '\n\r' + line)

                json = JSON.stringify(json[0])

                if (counter === 1) {
                    // Check for first Line
                    json = `[${json},`
                } else if (last) {
                    // Check for last Line
                    json = `${json}]`
                    resolve()
                } else {
                    // Check for inbetween Line
                    json = `${json},`
                }

                await fs.appendFile(editDumb, json)
            })
        })
    } catch (e) {
        throw new BaseError(`Error while converting CSV to JSON - Error: ${e}`)
    }
}
```